# Python script using Crontab

Tags: macos, python, cron, crontab, scheduling

I've written a python script that will check my roster for work (which is in google sheets), take some relevant details, place them in an email and send them to me.

When I run this script manually from IDLE, it works perfectly.

(my experience levels allow me to write this script and general use of python for day to day use, but the following is new to me...)

When I try to schedule this task however, is where my problem begins:

I've researched crontab (I'm using macOS). I wrote the crontab using help from articles online, however I never receive my email. I noticed when I open terminal again I have a message saying I have mail. I read the mail and it contains an error message. '....ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ezgmail'.

Obviously this is why I never receive my email!

Whenever I run the script manually (ie. open the python file in IDLE and run it from there) it works flawlessly.
Why is it the case that when it is run using crontab, there is a Module Not Found Error?

I hope I have provided enough details here and have explained my question correctly!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether this `ezgmail` module came with your OS, or was installed later. Depending on how it was installed, it could be that differences in the environment cause it to be found when you run your script in IDLE, and not found when run from crontab.

Python looks for modules in the directories specified in the `sys.path` list, and one of the ways in which that list gets populated is from the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. So one way to investigate your issue is to write a very simple script to query the values of `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH`, run it both in IDLE and from the crontab (you might need to write the values to a file, for the crontab case), and look for the directory where `ezgmail` is installed.

Also, be sure to check which user is running the script from the crontab.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and should get you to “see” the problem, which is probably PYTHONPATH as suggested.  My suggestion for fixing it, once you can see what’s missing in your cron, is to write a wrapper shell script that sets any missing vars, then calls your Python script. Call the shell script in cron, not your Python. Your cron env is very minimal, you always need to setup env vars manually like this in a wrapper.